# Routing with parameters - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to craft a route for a controller that will submit some data to a database. My URL is as follows:

```
http://example.co.uk/posts/5/edit?type=job
```

I've tried

```
Route::post('/posts/{id}/edit?type={role}', 'PostsContoller@store');
```

but am unsure if this will fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add parameters in your route:

```
Route::post('/posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsContoller@store');
```

In your controller, just check if parameter exist:

```
$type = Input::has('type') ? Input::get('type') : null;
```

Don't worry about HTTP verb, as `Input` access for all verbs (POST,GET,PUT,DELETE...).

**Edit**

As pointed out by @Antoine, you can simply specify the default value in the `get` method

```
$type = Input::get('type', null);
```

Comment: Two very good answers thanks. +1 for the use of the ternary operator @Razor

Comment: @AndrewCookson Just to point out that the signature is `Input::get($key, $default)` therefore `Input::get('type', null)` uses null if the key `type` is not here, you don't need a ternary. A minor improvement.

Comment: Actually `null` is the default default value, so it would literally just be `$type = Input::get('type');`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is the right way to do it.

## First way

If you change your route to

```
Route::post('/posts/{id}/edit/{role?}', 'PostsContoller@store');
```

You will then call the URL: `GET posts/42/edit/job`.

your `store` function in `PostsController` will be:

```
public function store($id, $role = null)
{
  // some code
}
```

## Second way

You can use another route like:

```
Route::post('/posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsContoller@store');
```

You will then call the URL: `GET posts/42/edit?type=job`

And you can get the type in your `store` function in `PostsController`:

```
public function store($id)
{
  // $role will be null if type is not in the URL 
  $role = Input::get('type', null);
  // additional code
}
```

I would personally go for the second way.